# < is converting into &lt;, whenever i am trying to send an xml request through SoapUI

Tags: xml, soapui

Whenever i am sending an xml request through SoapUI, but `<` is converting into `&lt;`

Below is the example for the same. Please help me, why it is converting into it?

```
**<**![CDATA[ **<**!DOCTYPE foo [<!ENTITY xxe SYSTEM "file:/export/home/1230/abc.txt">]>
```

getting response:

```
**/&lt**;!DOCTYPE foo [**&lt**;!ENTITY xxe SYSTEM "file:/export/home/1230/abc.txt">]>
```

Answer (score 2):

`&lt;` is the XML character entity for "less than", that's why your `<` gets converted to `&lt;`. (`<` is an invalid character in XML except for starting a tag).

Comment: Thanks Lajos, but can you please tell me, How can i restrict the conversion? because i really want to send "<" in my request.